# Finding Probability from branching process pgf

Tags: probability

I don't understand the answer to part f of this question. Could someone please explain it? How is it 'even'? What does being 'even' mean?

[image]

Comment: In English, "even" means "to be a multiple of 2" : "odd" means the contrary (being of the form $2n+1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p.g.f of the offspring distribution is $A(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}(\textrm{#offsprings}=k)\;z^k$. So $A(z) = p z^0 + (1-p)z^2$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{#offsprings}=k) = 0 \; \forall k \notin\{0,2\}$. Thus, $X_n $ is not odd for $n>0$, almost surely.

Comment: Somehow I suspect that the one-liner @JeanMarie posted as a comment might be more helpful to this OP...